# Center aligning the webpages

Tags: html, css

How do I center align the entire `body` content  of webpages?

I tried aligning through `text-align:center` but failed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
width:900px;
margin:auto;
```

Make sure it's not floated.

Comment: ohk .. I was missing `margin:auto`. Thanks my problem has been solved. But I dont understand why isnt the webpage centered when this is not set..

Comment: Because the default is `margin:0`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

CSS :

```
div#body {
    width:902px;  //Or whatever your content width is
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
}
```

How site will look like:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id"body">
            ...The rest of your content...
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can use jquery also :

```
$(window).resize(function(){

    $('.className').css({
        position:'absolute',
        left: ($(window).width() - $('.className').outerWidth())/2,
        top: ($(window).height() - $('.className').outerHeight())/2
    });

});

// To initially run the function:
$(window).resize();
```

Also a tutorial for you : http://tutorialzine.com/2010/03/centering-div-vertically-and-horizontally/